# How to change a word's color in td (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html

How to change `Weekend's` color to **blue**?

I'm using `razor` and I have a flag-enum which can directly convert to string like this:

```
var a = 1|2|6|7;
var weekdayStr=a.ToString();//weekdayStr=="Monday, Tuesday, Weekend"
```

And the html:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Monday, Tuesday, Weekend</td></tr></table>
```

How do I only change one word's color, not all text in td?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Hint: you'll need to wrap the text you want to style in some sort of HTML element.

Comment: it could be in a span, like `<td>Monday, <span class='blue'>Weekend</span></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.fn.replaceText = function( search, replace, text_only ) {
return this.each(function(){
  var node = this.firstChild,
    val,
    new_val,
    remove = [];
  if ( node ) {
    do {
      if ( node.nodeType === 3 ) {
        val = node.nodeValue;
        new_val = val.replace( search, replace );
        if ( new_val !== val ) {
          if ( !text_only && /</.test( new_val ) ) {
            $(node).before( new_val );
            remove.push( node );
          } else {
            node.nodeValue = new_val;
          }
        }
      }
    } while ( node = node.nextSibling );
  }
  remove.length && $(remove).remove();
});
};

$("td").replaceText( /Weekend/g, "<span>Weekend</span>" );  
$('td span').css('color', 'blue');
```

[reference from](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-jquery-replacetext/)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to either manually add an html tag, or find the td and modify it with jQuery.

```
$('td').html($('td').html().replace('Weekend', '<span>Weekend</span>'));
$('td span').css('color', 'blue');
```

[Something like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/gFppd/)

UPDATE:

[new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/gFppd/2/)

Comment: when there is `<td>Monday, Tuesday, Weekend</td>` it replace it to `Monday, Weekend`

Comment: Something must be different about your implementation: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/gFppd/1/)

Comment: try this `<table>
<tr><td>Monday, Weekend</td></tr>
<tr><td>Monday</td></tr>
<tr><td>Monday, Tuesday, Weekend</td></tr>
</table>​`

Comment: Also, this is the most basic (and least flexible) way to do this.  I stripped it down for simplicity's sake.  If you want a truly flexible way to do it, you'll have to specify a class/id instead of the `td` and place it all in a function for multiple usages

Comment: Updated my answer for a more usable version

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var build = '';
  var data = $('#yourtd_id').html().split(',');
  $.each(data,function(v){
         if(v == 'Weekend'){
          build+='<span style="color:blue">'+v+'</span>,';
         }else{
          build+='<span>'+v+'</span>,';
         }

  });  
$('#yourtd_id').html(build)

});
```